# Convert XML with repeated nodes to R data frame

Tags: xml, r, dataframe, flatten

I am trying to flatten XML with repeated nodes of the same name (but uniquely identified by an attribute value) to a flat data in R. The example I have is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
<tr id="1">
    <A id="100">100</A>
    <B>abc</B>
    <C>true</C>
</tr>
<tr id="2">
    <A id="200">200</A>
    <A id="300">300</A>
    <B>wxyz</B>
    <C>FALSE</C>
</tr>
</data>
```

The desired result is a data.frame that would look like

```
tr     A     B     C
 1   100   abc  true
 2   200  wxyz FALSE
 2   300  wxyz FALSE
```

I have read the xml ...

```
library(XML)
xmlfile <- "H:/My Documents/Code/R/xml/example.xml"
xmldoc <- xmlTreeParse(xmlfile)
```

Using xpathSApply(), I can retrieve each node and attribute without problem,  e.g.,

```
data.frame(id = xpathSApply(xmldoc, "//A", xmlGetAttr, "id"))
```

but I fail to organize the whole lot in a data.frame, because the number of "A" nodes is larger (3) than the number of all the other nodes (2).

Any help will be greatly appreciated ...

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to create a data.frame for each  node and combine the results.

```
tr <- getNodeSet(xmldoc, "//tr")
x <- lapply(tr, function(x)  data.frame(tr = xpathSApply(x, "." , xmlGetAttr, "id"),
                                         A = xpathSApply(x, ".//A", xmlValue),
                                         B = xpathSApply(x, ".//B", xmlValue),
                                         C = xpathSApply(x, ".//C", xmlValue) ))

do.call("rbind", x)
  tr   A    B     C
1  1 100  abc  true
2  2 200 wxyz FALSE
3  2 300 wxyz FALSE
```